# The same elements are being repeated every time in my card view when i tried to display my Json response (retrofit)

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

my JSON response begins with an JSON array which further contains three arrays inside it. And I want to display the content of these arrays in my card view.  It seems in each loop I am always changing the same ViewHolder so the result always will be the last item of the last loop. The `int i` in `onBindViewHolder` indicates the position of which item will be shown.

```
[
   {
"firstTeam_VS_secondTeam": [{
    "match_id": "248036",
    "country_id": "169",
    "country_name": "England",
    "league_id": "70",
    "league_name": "Capital One Cup",
    "match_date": "2018-01-24",
    "match_status": "FT",
    "match_time": "21:00",
    "match_hometeam_name": "Arsenal",
    "match_hometeam_score": "2",
    "match_awayteam_name": "Chelsea",
    "match_awayteam_score": "1",
    "match_hometeam_halftime_score": "1",
    "match_awayteam_halftime_score": "1",
    "match_live": "1"
},
.....
],"firstTeam_lastResults": [{
    "match_id": "248036",
    "country_id": "169",
    "country_name": "England",
    "league_id": "70",
    "league_name": "Capital One Cup",
    "match_date": "2018-01-24",
    "match_status": "FT",
    "match_time": "21:00",
    "match_hometeam_name": "Arsenal",
    "match_hometeam_score": "2",
    "match_awayteam_name": "Chelsea",
    "match_awayteam_score": "1",
    "match_hometeam_halftime_score": "1",
    "match_awayteam_halftime_score": "1",
    "match_live": "1"
},
.....
],  "secondTeam_lastResults": [{
    "match_id": "248036",
    "country_id": "169",
    "country_name": "England",
    "league_id": "70",
    "league_name": "Capital One Cup",
    "match_date": "2018-01-24",
    "match_status": "FT",
    "match_time": "21:00",
    "match_hometeam_name": "Arsenal",
    "match_hometeam_score": "2",
    "match_awayteam_name": "Chelsea",
    "match_awayteam_score": "1",
    "match_hometeam_halftime_score": "1",
    "match_awayteam_halftime_score": "1",
    "match_live": "1"
},
.....
]
```

My `Onbindviewholder` class, I tried this code but it is displaying same set of details in my all card views

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull footballmatchadapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    List<FirstTeamVSSecondTeam> firstTeamVSSecondTeams;
    List<FirstTeamLastResult> firstTeamLastResults;
    List<SecondTeamLastResult> secondTeamLastResults;
    firstTeamVSSecondTeams=post.getFirstTeamVSSecondTeam();
    firstTeamLastResults=post.getFirstTeamLastResults();
    secondTeamLastResults=post.getSecondTeamLastResults();
    viewHolder.tvleague.setText(firstTeamVSSecondTeams.size());
    viewHolder.tvhometeamscore.setText(firstTeamLastResults.size());
    viewHolder.tvdate.setText(secondTeamLastResults.size());
    if(post.getFirstTeamVSSecondTeam()!=null) {
        firstTeamVSSecondTeams = post.getFirstTeamVSSecondTeam();
    }
    if(post.getFirstTeamLastResults()!=null) {
        firstTeamLastResults = post.getFirstTeamLastResults();

    }
    if(post.getSecondTeamLastResults()!=null) {
        secondTeamLastResults = post.getSecondTeamLastResults();
    }
    String leauge="",date="",team1="",team2="",team1score="",team2score="";
    if(firstTeamVSSecondTeams!=null)
    {
        for(FirstTeamVSSecondTeam 
       firstTeamVSSecondTeam:firstTeamVSSecondTeams)
        {
            leauge=firstTeamVSSecondTeam.getLeagueName();
            date="Match Date "+firstTeamVSSecondTeam.getMatchDate();
            team1="Home Team "+firstTeamVSSecondTeam.getMatchHometeamName();
            team2="Second Team 
      "+firstTeamVSSecondTeam.getMatchAwayteamName();
            team1score=firstTeamVSSecondTeam.getMatchHometeamName()+" : 
      "+firstTeamVSSecondTeam.getMatchHometeamScore();
            team2score=firstTeamVSSecondTeam.getMatchAwayteamName()+" : 
       "+firstTeamVSSecondTeam.getMatchAwayteamScore();
            viewHolder.tvleague.setText(leauge);
            viewHolder.tvdate.setText(date);
            viewHolder.tvhometownteam.setText(team1);
            viewHolder.tvawayteam.setText(team2);
            viewHolder.tvhometeamscore.setText(team1score);
            viewHolder.tvawayteamscore.setText(team2score);

        }
    }
    if(firstTeamLastResults!=null)
    {
        for(FirstTeamLastResult firstTeamLastResult:firstTeamLastResults)
        {
            leauge=firstTeamLastResult.getLeagueName();
            date="Match Date "+firstTeamLastResult.getMatchDate();
            team1="Home Team "+firstTeamLastResult.getMatchHometeamName();
            team2="Second Team "+firstTeamLastResult.getMatchAwayteamName();
            team1score=firstTeamLastResult.getMatchHometeamName()+" : 
           "+firstTeamLastResult.getMatchHometeamScore();
            team2score=firstTeamLastResult.getMatchAwayteamName()+" : 
             "+firstTeamLastResult.getMatchAwayteamScore();
            viewHolder.tvleague.setText(leauge);
            viewHolder.tvdate.setText(date);
            viewHolder.tvhometownteam.setText(team1);
            viewHolder.tvawayteam.setText(team2);
            viewHolder.tvhometeamscore.setText(team1score);
            viewHolder.tvawayteamscore.setText(team2score);

        }
    }
    if(secondTeamLastResults!=null)
    {
        for(SecondTeamLastResult SecondTeamLastResult:secondTeamLastResults)
        {
            leauge=SecondTeamLastResult.getLeagueName();
            date="Match Date "+SecondTeamLastResult.getMatchDate();
            team1="Home Team "+SecondTeamLastResult.getMatchHometeamName();
            team2="Second Team 
     "+SecondTeamLastResult.getMatchAwayteamName();
            team1score=SecondTeamLastResult.getMatchHometeamName()+" : 
     "+SecondTeamLastResult.getMatchHometeamScore();
            team2score=SecondTeamLastResult.getMatchAwayteamName()+" : 
      "+SecondTeamLastResult.getMatchAwayteamScore();
            viewHolder.tvleague.setText(leauge);
            viewHolder.tvdate.setText(date);
            viewHolder.tvhometownteam.setText(team1);
            viewHolder.tvawayteam.setText(team2);
            viewHolder.tvhometeamscore.setText(team1score);
            viewHolder.tvawayteamscore.setText(team2score);

        }
    }
}
```

This is my `ongetItemCount` function which is returning the sum of the sizes of all the three Arrays

```
 @Override
public int getItemCount() {
    int v1 = post.getFirstTeamVSSecondTeam() != null ?
            post.getFirstTeamVSSecondTeam().size() : 0;
    int v2 = post.getFirstTeamLastResults() != null ?
            post.getFirstTeamLastResults().size() : 0;
    int v3 = post.getSecondTeamLastResults() != null ?
            post.getSecondTeamLastResults().size() : 0;
    return v1 + v2 + v3;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it seems you don't need a diferent class for each list of results. You should to create a class like:

```
public class MatchResults {
    @SerializedName("match_id")
    private long matchId;

    @SerializedName("country_id")
    private long countryId;

    @SerializedName("country_name")
    private String countryName;
    ...
}
```

Your adapter should looks like:

```
public class FootballMatchAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FootballMatchAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<MatchResults> firstTeamVSSecondTeams;
        private List<MatchResults> firstTeamLastResults;
        private List<MatchResults> secondTeamLastResults;

    public FootbalMatchAdapter() {
        loadData();
    }

    private void loadData() {
        firstTeamVSSecondTeams = post.getFirstTeamVSSecondTeam();
        firstTeamLastResults = post.getFirstTeamLastResults();
        secondTeamLastResults = post.getSecondTeamLastResults();
    }

    private int getFirstTeamVSSecondTeamsSize() {
        return (firstTeamVSSecondTeams != null ? 
                firstTeamVSSecondTeams.size() : 0); 
    }

    private int getFirstTeamLastResultsSize() {
        return (firstTeamLastResults != null ? 
                firstTeamLastResults.size() : 0); 
    }

    private int getSecondTeamLastResultsSize() {
        return (secondTeamLastResults != null ? 
                secondTeamLastResults.size() : 0); 
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return getFirstTeamVSSecondTeamsSize() 
        + getFirstTeamLastResultsSize()
        + getSecondTeamLastResultsSize();
    }

    private MatchResults getItem(int i) {
        if (i < 0 || i > getItemCount())
            return null;
        if (i >= (getFirstTeamVSSecondTeamsSize() + getFirstTeamLastResultsSize())) {
            int pos = i - (getFirstTeamVSSecondTeamsSize() + getFirstTeamLastResultsSize());
            return secondTeamLastResults.get(pos);
        }
        else if (i >= getFirstTeamVSSecondTeamsSize()) {
            int pos = i - getFirstTeamVSSecondTeamsSize();
            return firstTeamLastResults.get(pos);
        }
        else {
            return firstTeamVSSecondTeams.get(i);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public FootballMatchAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        ... 
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull footballmatchadapter.ViewHolder 
        viewHolder, int i) {

        String leauge = "", date = "", team1 = "", team2 = "", team1score = "", team2score = "";
        MatchResult result = getItem(i);

        leauge = firstTeamVSSecondTeam.getLeagueName();
        date = "Match Date " + firstTeamVSSecondTeam.getMatchDate();
        team1 = "Home Team " + firstTeamVSSecondTeam.getMatchHometeamName();
        team2 = "Second Team " + firstTeamVSSecondTeam.getMatchAwayteamName();
        team1score = firstTeamVSSecondTeam.getMatchHometeamName() + " : "+firstTeamVSSecondTeam.getMatchHometeamScore();
        team2score = firstTeamVSSecondTeam.getMatchAwayteamName() + " : "+firstTeamVSSecondTeam.getMatchAwayteamScore();

        viewHolder.tvleague.setText(leauge);
        viewHolder.tvdate.setText(date);
        viewHolder.tvhometownteam.setText(team1);
        viewHolder.tvawayteam.setText(team2);
        viewHolder.tvhometeamscore.setText(team1score);
        viewHolder.tvawayteamscore.setText(team2score);
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ...
    }
}
```

I didn't run this code so probably it has some errors.